# how to extract or get int vaue from string in a hashmap value

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap<String,String> dataRules = new HashMap<String,String>();

dataRules.put("FAX_GW_NW_ELE_DM_","VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)");
```

In the above given expression I need to extract 32 BYTE as int 32 from value to use. Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: As an aside, it's worth noting that your problem really doesn't have anything to do with the fact the value is in a map. You're trying to extract the int value 32 from the string "VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)" - where that string comes from is at least somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @KevinEsche: In this case, that would leave 232...

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad, didn´t really see the 2 in the varchar...

Comment: I am trying with substring , hope it will work ,its ok .  thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
package general;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchNumber {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> extractInt(String mapValue) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(mapValue);

        //  throw new NumberFormatException("For input string [" + mapValue + "]");
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (matcher.find()){
            array.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
        }
        return array;
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> result = extractInt("VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)");
    for (int i : result){
        System.out.println(i);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: In the OP's case, that will return 2 due to the VARCHAR2.

Comment: Now this example should print both 2 as well as 32

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the fixed prefix and sufix you can extract it like this

```
Integer.valueOf(strVal.substring(9,strVal.indexOf("BYTE)") ))
```

where 9 is length of `"VARCHAR2("` plus 1

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. `strVal.indexOf("VARCHAR2(")` returns `0`. So substring method returns `"VARCHAR2(32"` instead of `32`

Comment: Correct, I modified it.

Answer (score 0):

in case the the type value, as varchar2, will differ, but the number will be allways written in paranthesis you could use `String#replaceAll` with a capturing group to extract the number.

```
String input = "VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(".*\\((\\d*).*", "$1"));
```

output

```
32
```